# Is there an enforced death penalty in effect for homosexuality in Somalia?

Tags: death, somalia, homosexuality

[image]

According to the info graphic, Somalia has an enforced death penalty in effect for homosexuality. Is this truly the case, and how much is it actually enforced?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149236/discussion-on-question-by-seeking-answers-is-there-an-enforced-death-penalty-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

[A joint submission](https://www.ohchr.org/sites/default/files/lib-docs/HRBodies/UPR/Documents/Session11/SO/JS5_JointSubmission5-eng.pdf) (by Arc International, Geneva, Switzerland; International Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual,
Trans and Intersex Association; International Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual, Trans and
Intersex Association –Europe, (Consultative Status); Pan Africa - International
Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual, Trans and Intersex Association) to the First Cycle (2011) of the [Universal Periodic Review](https://www.ohchr.org/en/hr-bodies/upr/upr-home) of Somalia said:

> In southern parts of Somalia, Sharia law may allow punishing homosexual acts with death penalty or flogging.

A 2017 report (ILGA, [*State-Sponsored Homophobia*](https://ilga.org/downloads/2017/ILGA_State_Sponsored_Homophobia_2017_WEB.pdf)) reports arrests within the previous three years, and reports that there is an *implemented* death penalty for sexual acts between males and for sexual acts between females in *southern* Somalia. See the map at [p. 194](https://ilga.org/downloads/2017/ILGA_State_Sponsored_Homophobia_2017_WEB.pdf#page=194). The report notes that in southern Somalia, "Sharia law explicitly forbids homosexuality - the punishment for those 'found guilty' is at a judge's discretion, and may be punished by death" ([p. 99](https://ilga.org/downloads/2017/ILGA_State_Sponsored_Homophobia_2017_WEB.pdf#page=99)).

It describes the situation at [p. 40](https://ilga.org/downloads/2017/ILGA_State_Sponsored_Homophobia_2017_WEB.pdf#page=40), that the death penalty is "codified under Sharia and implemented provincially" in "Somalia (southern parts)."